# Firebase (Storage Exception) - User does not have permission

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

**Goal: Allowing authenticated user to upload profile photo ( and associate it to THAT user).**

*Note:* I followed the user doc at : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

*Problem:* I am getting the error:

```
StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
        User does not have permission to access this object.
        Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403

StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
          java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
```

*Testing done:*
I first had my rules like the following, and *was able to allow an authenticated user to upload a photo* (but it was not associated with that user):
[Authenticated Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs18t.jpg)

I changed my *rule* to the following to associate the image with a userid:
[Associate Image to UserID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBJ2u.jpg)

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null;
   }
   match /images {
     // Only an individual user can write to "their" images
     match /{userId}/{imageId} {
       allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
     }
   }

  }  
}
```

With the new rule that was supposed to associated the photo to the user ID, I get the Storage Exception error about not having permission.

This is my storage reference if it matters:

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://app-name.appspot.com").child("20170702_174811.jpeg"); //was PNG
```

And:

```
public void handleChooseImage(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);  //then goes to onActivityResult
    }
```

In addition to documentation I've tried watching as many YouTube videos as possible on the subject but seem to be missing something. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There are two (maybe three) issues here:

1. You have two overlapping rules
2. Your reference isn't pointing to the correct place
3. It's not clear to me if you're actually using [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)

1: you have a rule on all files (`{allPaths=**}`) that requires only authentication, while a second, more specific one that requires per-user auth. It's likely that you only want:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{userId}/{imageId} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }  
}
```

2: you're pointing to a single file name, rather than the `/images/{userId}/{imageId}` path. Instead, do:

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
String imageId = "myFile.png"  // or whatever you want to call it
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference ref = storage.getReference()
                         .child("images")
                         .child(userId)
                         .child(imageId);
```

3: Use Firebase Auth and sign in with a provider, if you aren't already.